# Unable to login to Raspberry Pi Linux after locale change

Tags: linux, authentication, locale, raspberry-pi

I changed the keyboard mapping on my Raspberry Pi and am no longer able to login (because the keys I press are interpreted very differently; a "p" is an "r" etc.). Has anyone run into this and is there an easier way to fix this than to re-image the OS on my SD card?

Contents of my SD card
[image: Contents of my SD card]

Comment: can you access your sd card from within another linux system ?

Comment: Good question. I've added an image of the contents of my SD card.

Comment: Do you remember what you did to make the key-mappings a mess ? and can you ssh to it ?

Comment: If you can ssh to it, you can try to undo what you've done to make the key mappings normal.   
If not you can try [this website](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_ConfigurationFile) and see what you can do with the sd card. Because I don't have a raspberry PI so I've no idea what to do with those config files, either.

Comment: I tried renaming kernel_emergency.img to kernel.img. However the bootup process hangs. So, I am re-imaging the card.

Comment: Thanks your comments will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for the benefit of others. As yakiang suggested, ssh into your raspberry pi (this assumes you enabled the ssh deamon to run your pi upon each boot up before this problem occurred). Edit /etc/default/locale and /etc/default/keyboard to the correct settings as follows.

/etc/default/locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

/etc/default/keyboard
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"